# How do I get default colors to my default theme

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**This is in my App.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="Checkbox">
<Setter Property="BorderBrush"              Value="{DynamicResource WieoRed}" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness"          Value="2" />
<Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"        Value="Top" />
<Setter Property="Margin"                   Value="20,15,0,0" />
<Setter Property="FontFamily"               Value="/Resources/Fonts/Source Sans Pro/#Source Sans Pro" />
<Setter Property="FontSize"                 Value="14" />
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"      Value="Left" />
<Setter Property="Foreground"               Value="{DynamicResource CheckboxForegroundColor}" />
<Setter Property="Background"               Value="{DynamicResource CheckboxBackgroundColor}" />
<Setter Property="BorderBrush"              Value="{DynamicResource CheckboxBorderbrushColor}"/>
```

**This is in my darkTheme.xaml (Colors Works fine )**

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxForegroundColor"                Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxBackgroundColor"                Color="#FF2d2d30"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxBorderbrushColor"               Color="#FFCC1517"/>
```

**This is in my defaultTheme.xaml**

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxForegroundColor"                Color="Black"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxBackgroundColor"                Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxBorderbrushColor"               Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxIsCheckedColor"                 Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}}"/>
```

In my DarkTheme.xaml and DefaultTheme.xaml I only create my colors and in App.xaml Iam Binding them to the colors, but when i change to Default Theme on Runtime most of the colors becomes white. Is there default style for every control like buttons, foreground, background, textblock, checkboxes etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is already default looks for controls, but you can use control templates to overrun these default looks

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I dont want to overrun my default looks. I want to have the default windows standard style when i select my DefaultTheme. I dont understand why I wont get the default styles in my DefaultTheme.xaml, i have set the colors to windowcolorkey so why isnt working?

Answer (score 0):

I have played around with similar and have this offering for you.  I wanted to allow testing of different colors without having to recompile an application.  This way, others who had visual color design could change an external file I was looking for and load their color schemes.

So, how it works is you have your normal color scheme applicable to the application.  If you then read a new resource dictionary and MERGE it into the current, any new values will be added, but if there is an existing key value, it will be overwritten and applied without changing the rest of the design / look and feel.  (or Application Resources...)

So adjust as needed, but what I did was a simple read from a XAML file which is your defaultTheme.xaml.  From there parse into a resource dictionary.  Then merge into whatever your Resources are (generic Window, Grid, whatever).

```
try
{
   var strXaml = File.ReadAllText( [your defaultTheme.xaml file] );    
   var dict = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Parse(strXaml);
   YourWindow.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
}
catch
{
   // error if invalid xaml / resource dictionary content
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think you misunderstood me. I have no problem to change my Themes in runtime. The only problem is that in my defaultThemes.xaml i have set all colors to WindowColorKey and almost all the colors becomes white. It must be some easy way around this